# How can I get the drop down selected value without using submit button?

Tags: php, html

I want to store the dropdown selected value, and I want to pass that selected value to next page.To do this I want to store the drop down selected value with our using any button. By using submit button I can do this.

My code is,

```
<?php
include_once 'Connection.php';
$sql = "select project_name from project";
$result_sql = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo '<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="project_name" id="project_name">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sql)) {
                echo "<option>" . $row['project_name'] ."</option>";    
            }
echo'</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['project_name'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
//echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

Comment: You can do this using jQuery. 
$('#project_name : selected').val()

Comment: Or simply add in `<form action=` next php page file

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is run on the server (and not on the client like JavaScript), the form has to be submitted one way or another so that your PHP code is run. You can submit a form either with a submit button, with JavaScript or by pressing enter from a text input field.

Depending on how you submit the form, `$_POST['submit']` may not always be set. You should check if `$_POST['project_name']` is set instead.

Comment: "not working" is not a valid error description. What have you tried, what did you expect to happen, what happened instead?

Comment: I want to store the selected project name in $selected_val without click on any submit button.          I tried without submit button and like this,       if(isset($_POST['project_name'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['project_name'];  but project_name is not get stored in  $selected_val variable.

Comment: How did you submit the form? Even without the submit button, you have to submit the form somehow.